Не работает POST запрос в мобильном приложении .NET MAUI
Я пробую создать клиент-серверное мобильное приложение с помощью MAUI и ASP.NET Core 8.  В клиенте приложения есть кнопка, по нажатию    которой в базу данных (PostgreSQL) через API записывается тестовая    строчка каждую секунду.  Эмулятор Android и сервер запускаются на    локальной машине. Сервер вроде бы работает, потому что тестовые    запросы через swagger отрабатывают верно, запись в БД появляется,    также отрабатывают запросы с приложения API Tester на телефоне    (реальном). Но при нажатии на кнопку, выскакивает исключение    "Connection failure".  Возможно дело в адресе POST запроса или в end    point'е ?  Порты менять пробовал, в json файлах сервера у меня    следующее:
1. appsettings.json
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Database=SensorDataDb;Username=postgres;Password=123"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      }
    }
  }
}

2. launchSettings.json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49050",
      "sslPort": 44370
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5293",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7130;http://localhost:5293",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

3. Код метода из клиента мобильного приложения
private async Task SendDataAsync()
{
 
    while (_isSending)
    {
        var data = new
        {
            Data = "Sample data from mobile app"
        };

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

       Jsonlabel.Text = json;

        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        try
        {
            var response = await _client.PostAsync("http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/SensorData", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = $"Request error: {httpRequestException.Message}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = $"Error: {responseBody}";

        }

        await Task.Delay(1000); 
    }


10.0.2.2 - это чей IP? Вашей локальной сети или эмулятора? Если локальной сети, то вот ваша проблема, ибо любой эмулятор по умолчанию работает в своей сети и он ничего не знает о внешней, пока вы не настроите его самостоятельно нужным образом. P.S. Перемудрили с отправкой POST, ибо весь ваш код можно сократить простым _client.PoastAsJsonAsync("http://...", data); и в обратную сторону получение .ReadFromJsonAsync<...>();

10.0.2.2 это аналог localhost, о котором знает эмулятор, как я понял из документации у microsoft
доступность я проверил ping'ом, через консоль adb Android
Я пробовал также запустить разрабатываемое приложение на своем телефоне физическом, который находился в той же сети, используя адрес компьютера в сети, используя localhost,ошибка та же
Спасибо за мини-рефакторинг !!!

Ответ нашелся !
Возможно, ваша проблема связана с настройками безопасности на устройстве Android. Добавьте параметр UsesCleartextTraffic = true on [Application]
MainApplication.cs (в папке Platforms/Android)
namespace MauiApp1
{
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic =true)]
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
}
источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77898089/http-connection-failure-when-calling-local-api-from-net-maui-view

UsesCleartextTraffic отключает шифрование и делает соединение небезопасным.
